# Mac Terminal: Avoid password

Tags: terminal, mac, command-line

I‘m trying to make a siri-shortcut which let you shutdown your mac.

https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/7c625a68308740d9b84cc0eaa9353055

The command is:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

But when I run this command I must enter my password can I do something to run this command without the password?

[image]

Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 3):

It could be configured to make `sudo` skip password prompt for specific command with `/etc/sudoers`.

```sh
# modify /etc/sudoers with visudo
# never open it directly with an editor
sudo visudo
```

Append the following conf into the file,

```
Cmnd_Alias SHUTDOWN_NOW = /sbin/shutdown -h now
%admin ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: SHUTDOWN_NOW
```

Done.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the issue entirely by taking another approach to shutting down the computer:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to shut down'
```

This will also prompt you to save any unsaved documents, just as if you'd selected "Shut Down" from the Apple menu.

Comment: Thanks!!! is this also working for sudo shutdown -h +10 or sudo killall shutdown? If yes, can you please exlpain me how?

Comment: No. The whole point is that this doesn't require `sudo`.

Comment: I mean, is there another osascript command which let you cancel the shutdown or to shutdown the Mac in 10 minutes? Sorry for the misunderstanding :(

Comment: No. Again, this command works exactly as if you had initiated a shutdown from the menu bar.

Answer (score 2):

The common way to do this is to allow your user to run the shutdown command without entering a password.

You that by opening Terminal.app and then run the following command:

```
sudo visudo
```

This gives you an editor where you can edit the sudoers configuration file.

Add the following line at the bottom:

```
jonathan ALL=(ALL) /sbin/shutdown
```

After saving, you should be able to run shutdown with your user without having to enter a password.

Note that you should replace "jonathan" with your actual username.